# Keeping Column Name in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a dataframe `df` with the following column names: `['input.Name', 'input.Number']`

When I do `df_new = df.select("input.Name")` the column name becomes `['Name']` when looking at `df_new.columns`. How do I preserve the original column names?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: You can use backtick (\`) to preserve column names containing special characters like `.`. 
For instance, df_new = df.select("\`input.Name\`")

Answer (score 0):

You should practise not using dots(.) in column names as dots are used to refer to nested data structures.
Example:

```
{
  "input": {
      "Name": "test",
      "Id": "test2"
  }
}
```

Here, `input.Name` refers to `test`.

If you still want to use dots(.), you can use backticks(`) to quote you column names as suggested by Nitish.

```
df_new = df.select("`input.Name`")
```

This will preserve the original column names.